# Read/Write speed monitor of NFS

Tags: filesystems, nfs, storage

I would like to see the disk read/write speeds for a network attached storage drive mounted via NFS. I am copying large amounts of files from a local disk to the network attached drive.

running `df -h` I can see:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb2                219G  190G   19G  92% /
/dev/sdb1                511M  6.7M  505M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1                4.9T  2.9T  1.9T  61% /home
private.com:/archive      60T   48T   12T  80% /home/archive
```

I can run `iostat -d /dev/sda1` to see the stats of the local drive.

How do I get a similar result with the network drive `private.com:/archive`?

Thanks :)

Comment: by using `nfsiostat` maybe ? (as mount point looks like NFS)

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for!